# ggplot2 is not plotting two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am having a complete brain fart right now. Why is the following code not plotting two lines for each category of the variable `Ford`? To my mind, I have the variable mapped as a grouping variable and then an aesthetic (col) in both `geom_point()` and `geom_line()`. I feel like I'm just overlooking something very basic.

```
#libraries
library(tidyverse)
#data
structure(list(stressx = c(0, 0.33, 0.67, 1, 0, 0.33, 0.67, 1, 
0, 0.33, 0.67, 1, 0, 0.33, 0.67, 1), visiblex = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), ford = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), preds = c(0.166275511711196, 
0.25404479263251, 0.344473748733258, 0.432243029654572, 0.417891216538386, 
0.449861131692899, 0.482799832155125, 0.514769747309638, 0.166275511711196, 
0.25404479263251, 0.344473748733258, 0.432243029654572, 0.417891216538386, 
0.449861131692899, 0.482799832155125, 0.514769747309638), se.fit =             
c(0.0216850668407667, 
0.0140669010411715, 0.014932848560481, 0.0233259879905658,         
0.0546688696666978, 
0.034867400606124, 0.0282122239553816, 0.0418803253364085,     
0.0216850668407667, 
0.0140669010411715, 0.014932848560481, 0.0233259879905658, 
0.0546688696666978, 
0.034867400606124, 0.0282122239553816, 0.0418803253364085)), .Names = 
c("stressx", 
"visiblex", "ford", "preds", "se.fit"), out.attrs = structure(list(
dim = structure(c(4L, 2L, 2L), .Names = c("stressx", "visiblex", 
"ford")), dimnames = structure(list(stressx = c("stressx=0.0000000", 
"stressx=0.3333333", "stressx=0.6666667", "stressx=1.0000000"
), visiblex = c("visiblex=0", "visiblex=1"), ford = c("ford=0", 
"ford=1")), .Names = c("stressx", "visiblex", "ford"))), .Names = c("dim", 
"dimnames")), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")`
```

My plot

```
newdat %>% 
mutate(visiblex=recode_factor(visiblex, `0`="Not Visible Minority",     
`1`="Visible Minority"), ford=recode_factor(ford, `0`="Disapprove",    
`1`="Approve"), stressx=recode_factor(stressx, `0`='Strongly disagree',     
`0.33`='Somewhat disagree', `0.67`='Somewhat agree', `1`='Strongly agree')) 
%>% 
rename(Stress=stressx, Visible=visiblex, Ford=ford, Prob=preds) %>% 
#filter(Ford=='Approve') %>% 
ggplot(., aes(x=Stress, y=Prob, group=Ford))+ 
geom_point(aes(col=Ford))+
geom_line(aes(col=Ford))+
facet_wrap(~Visible)+
ylim(c(0,1))+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=0.5))`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have **identical** data points for both levels of the factor variable `Ford`. I have modified your code slightly to show the data and then plotted the data with `geom_jitter` instead of `geom_point` and now you can see both data points. Since the underlying datapoints are identical, the lines drawn through those data points are also overlapping and only one of them is visible.

```r
#libraries
library(tidyverse)
#data
newdat <- structure(
  list(
    stressx = c(0, 0.33, 0.67, 1, 0, 0.33, 0.67, 1,
                0, 0.33, 0.67, 1, 0, 0.33, 0.67, 1),
    visiblex = c(0, 0, 0, 0,
                 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    ford = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    preds = c(
      0.166275511711196,
      0.25404479263251,
      0.344473748733258,
      0.432243029654572,
      0.417891216538386,
      0.449861131692899,
      0.482799832155125,
      0.514769747309638,
      0.166275511711196,
      0.25404479263251,
      0.344473748733258,
      0.432243029654572,
      0.417891216538386,
      0.449861131692899,
      0.482799832155125,
      0.514769747309638
    ),
    se.fit =
      c(
        0.0216850668407667,
        0.0140669010411715,
        0.014932848560481,
        0.0233259879905658,
        0.0546688696666978,
        0.034867400606124,
        0.0282122239553816,
        0.0418803253364085,
        0.0216850668407667,
        0.0140669010411715,
        0.014932848560481,
        0.0233259879905658,
        0.0546688696666978,
        0.034867400606124,
        0.0282122239553816,
        0.0418803253364085
      )
  ),
  .Names =
    c("stressx",
      "visiblex", "ford", "preds", "se.fit"),
  out.attrs = structure(
    list(
      dim = structure(c(4L, 2L, 2L), .Names = c("stressx", "visiblex",
                                                "ford")),
      dimnames = structure(
        list(
          stressx = c(
            "stressx=0.0000000",
            "stressx=0.3333333",
            "stressx=0.6666667",
            "stressx=1.0000000"
          ),
          visiblex = c("visiblex=0", "visiblex=1"),
          ford = c("ford=0",
                   "ford=1")
        ),
        .Names = c("stressx", "visiblex", "ford")
      )
    ),
    .Names = c("dim",
               "dimnames")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -16L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

#my plot
data <- newdat %>%
  mutate(
    visiblex = recode_factor(visiblex, `0` = "Not Visible Minority",
                             `1` = "Visible Minority"),
    ford = recode_factor(ford, `0` = "Disapprove",
                         `1` =
                           "Approve"),
    stressx = recode_factor(
      stressx,
      `0` = 'Strongly disagree',
      `0.33` =
        'Somewhat disagree',
      `0.67` = 'Somewhat agree',
      `1` = 'Strongly agree'
    )
  ) %>%
  dplyr::rename(
    Stress = stressx,
    Visible = visiblex,
    Ford = ford,
    Prob = preds
  ) 

# display data
data
#>               Stress              Visible       Ford      Prob     se.fit
#> 1  Strongly disagree Not Visible Minority Disapprove 0.1662755 0.02168507
#> 2  Somewhat disagree Not Visible Minority Disapprove 0.2540448 0.01406690
#> 3     Somewhat agree Not Visible Minority Disapprove 0.3444737 0.01493285
#> 4     Strongly agree Not Visible Minority Disapprove 0.4322430 0.02332599
#> 5  Strongly disagree     Visible Minority Disapprove 0.4178912 0.05466887
#> 6  Somewhat disagree     Visible Minority Disapprove 0.4498611 0.03486740
#> 7     Somewhat agree     Visible Minority Disapprove 0.4827998 0.02821222
#> 8     Strongly agree     Visible Minority Disapprove 0.5147697 0.04188033
#> 9  Strongly disagree Not Visible Minority    Approve 0.1662755 0.02168507
#> 10 Somewhat disagree Not Visible Minority    Approve 0.2540448 0.01406690
#> 11    Somewhat agree Not Visible Minority    Approve 0.3444737 0.01493285
#> 12    Strongly agree Not Visible Minority    Approve 0.4322430 0.02332599
#> 13 Strongly disagree     Visible Minority    Approve 0.4178912 0.05466887
#> 14 Somewhat disagree     Visible Minority    Approve 0.4498611 0.03486740
#> 15    Somewhat agree     Visible Minority    Approve 0.4827998 0.02821222
#> 16    Strongly agree     Visible Minority    Approve 0.5147697 0.04188033

# plot the data
data %>%
  #filter(Ford=='Approve') %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(data = .,
                  mapping = aes(x = Stress, y = Prob, group = Ford, colour = Ford)) +
  ggplot2::geom_jitter() + # change this back geom_point()
  ggplot2::geom_line() +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap( ~ Visible) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).